# Java Date Format Issue

Tags: java

I have the number of seconds from 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 i.e. (EST) and I want to convert the same to a date format.

I have the following code which returns any invalid date. Can anyone point out what seems to be the issue here.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class sample 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Date d1 = new Date(1000*1373604190); //Converting to millisecond
         String formattedDate = df.format(d1); 
         System.out.println(formattedDate); //I'm getting 22/Dec/1969 16:50:55
    }
}
```

How can I solve this.

Comment: `1000*1373604190` what does this number represent you think ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi : The number of milliseconds ,the seconds I have is 1373604190

Comment: @morgano : I have edited the question 31 DEC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `int` literals instead of `long` in your numbers. By default a integral literal is `int` unless you specify that is `long` with L at the end. Try this:

```
Date d1 = new Date(1000*1373604190L);
```

(note the L at the end of your literal 1373604190)

Comment: Yikes, forgot to add L. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a method where I can pass the seconds itself instead of converting it to ms. Or is there any better alternative to this method.

Comment: If you are already given the number of seconds, I don't know another alternative, but for sure there must be a Java library around that helps you better with that. Google is you friend ;-)

Comment: I see that there is a set seconds method and its working but is deprecated. Not sure whether this is the fastest way.

Comment: My advice would be: if deprecated then don't use. You could code a helper class with a static method that would transform from seconds to millis, and then you could use something like this: `Date d1 = new Date(Helper.toMillis(myDateInSeconds));` or even better, the helper could give you the Date object: `Date d1 = Helper.toDate(myDateInSeconds);`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochSeconds( 1_373_604_190L ) 
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss" , Locale.CANADA ) )
```

## Details

> the number of seconds from 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 i.e. (EST)

Do not think parochially when doing date-time work. Rather than translate values such as the [epoch reference moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) in and out of your own zone, just think in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Consider UTC to be *The One True Time*, all others being variations on that theme.

So, always refer to the epoch reference moment as `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, the first moment of 1970 in UTC, rather than in any other time zone.

> (EST)

Also, never use those 3-4 letter abbreviations as time zones. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Those 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## Using java.time

The modern way to do this work is with the java.time classes.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = 1_373_604_190L ;
```

We convert that to a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSeconds( secondsSinceEpoch ) ;
```

To see this value through the lens of some [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone as a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

I am guessing that by `EST` you meant the time zone used by much of the eastern portions of the United States and Canada. I will arbitrarily choose the time zone `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( "America/New_York" );
```

> secondsSinceEpoch: 1373604190
>
> instant.toString(): 2013-07-12T04:43:10Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2013-07-12T00:43:10-04:00[America/New_York]

See [live code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/VIoAO4).

### Strings

To generate a string, you can either let java.time automatically localize or you can specify an explicit formatting pattern.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA ;
DateTimeFormatter formatterLocalized = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale );
String outputLocalized = zdt.format( formatterLocalized );
```

> 12-Jul-2013 12:43:10 AM

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterCustom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss" , locale );
String output = zdt.format( formatterCustom );
```

> 12 Jul 2013 00:43:10

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).